# PHP container can't connect to MySQL container

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to connect to containerized MySQL DB from PHP container although all the containers on the same network, the issue is I keep getting `Connection failed: invalid data source name` when I hit `http://localhost:8080/dbTest.php` although I've checked that the credential is correct and the *demo* DB exists using `mysql -u root -p`

I see this message in *mysql* log **mbind: Operation not permitted** could be related?
Thanks

**Apache Dockerfile**

```
FROM httpd:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
COPY demo.apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf"  >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

**cmd**: *docker run -p 8080:80/tcp -v /home/hmalabeh/tutorial/docker/lamp/files/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ --link=php --name apache --network backend -i 8f704f51962d*

---

**PHP Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2.7-fpm-alpine3.7
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
EXPOSE 9000
```

**cmd**: *docker run -p 9000:9000 -v /home/hmalabeh/tutorial/docker/lamp/files/:/var/www/html/ --name php --network backend -i 1cc049496b03*

---

**MySQL Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

**cmd**: *docker run -p 3306:3306 -p 33060:33060 --name mysql --network backend --link=php -i 7bb7d4985301*

---

**dbTest.php**

```
<?php
class DBConnect
{
    private $dsn = "mysql:dbname=demo;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;";
    private $dbUsername = "root";
    private $dbPassword = "root";
    private $conn;

    public function connect()
    {
        try {
            echo 'Attempt Connection.     ';
            $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);

            echo 'Connected successfully.      ';
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $exception->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}


$co = new DBConnect();
$co->connect();
?>
```

My running containers

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
9639160c0824        8f704f51962d        "httpd-foreground"       2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                               apache
38e630a9cb01        7bb7d4985301        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33060->33060/tcp   mysql
c7f6e8db26a9        1cc049496b03        "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                             php
```

Comment: `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in Docker almost always means “this container”.

Comment: @DavidMaze days of sufferings to solve my connection problem ( redis and mysql ) ends by your small comment ; thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to add `$->this` before the variable, the code should be like below.

```
<?php
class DBConnect
{
    private $dsn = "mysql:host=mysql;dbname=demo;port=3306;charset=utf8";
    private $dbUsername = "root";
    private $dbPassword = "root";
    private $conn;

    public function connect()
    {
        try {
            echo 'Attempt Connection.     ';
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);

            echo 'Connected successfully.      ';
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $exception->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}


$co = new DBConnect();
$co->connect();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `host` to the DSN using the name of the container since they are in the same network:

```
private $dsn = "mysql:host=mysql;dbname=demo;port=3306;";
```

[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)

Comment: @HassanMalabeh are you sure they're both in the same network?

Comment: Running the command `docker network inspect backend` I can see that these three containers on the same network.

Comment: What version of Docker are you running @HassanMalabeh?

Comment: This is the version I use `Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc`

Comment: I just checked and I am able to connect to a container just using the name of the container while in the same network using both MySQLi and PDO (here is PDO `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql5725;dbname=grocery;charset=utf8', USER, PASS);` So there must be an issue with your network.

Comment: Did you create the network before joining it? `docker network create backend`?

Comment: Yes I have created the network before the containers joined it.

Comment: OK. At this point, without being able to see your setup, I cannot be of any further help.

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled remote access in mySql?

> nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

replace:
`bind-address= 127.0.0.1`
for
`bind-address= 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this didn't solve the issue either.

Comment: Please check:-
`root@01c710675b48:/# mysqld --verbose --help | grep bind-address`

`  --bind-address=name IP address(es) to bind to. Syntax: address[,address]...,`

`  --mysqlx-bind-address[=name] `

`bind-address                                                 0.0.0.0`

`mysqlx-bind-address                                          0.0.0.0`